# Cannot initialize the value of an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, initialization

I am still new to VBA. here is the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim NumberSeq() As Integer = {1,2,3,4}
End Sub
```

It's just the initialization of an array and I saw it work for others. But I always get the warning window: Compile error: Expected: end of statement with highlight on the equal mark"="

Don't know what happened here. Please advice, thank you a lot!!

Comment: VBA doesn't support declaration and assignment in one line.

Comment: Closest you could get might be `Dim a(): a = [{1,2,3}]` - but note that's a variant array not an integer one

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub macro1()
Dim NumberSeq() As Variant

NumberSeq = Array(1, 2, 3, 4) 'an allocated array with length 1 to 4

'check output through print
For i = LBound(NumberSeq) To UBound(NumberSeq)
    msg = msg & NumberSeq(i) & vbNewLine
Next i
MsgBox (msg)

End Sub
```

For implicitly sized 2 dimensional arrays use Array(row start To row end, col start to col end).

Here is a good [resource](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for both of your help! It works! It seems without the "As Variant" also works. And thank you for sharing the website resource:)

Comment: No problem! there is a lot of great information there. If I answered your question please click the check mark next to my answer, thanks!